# floated thumbnail gallery, with extra thumbnail content on hover. How to allow hovered thumbnail to overlap neighbors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a gallery of thumbnail images.  Below each image, I display the thumbnail title:

```
<div class='gallery'>
  <div class='thumb'>
    <div class='thumbimage'></div>
    <div class='thumbtitle'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='thumb'>
    <div class='thumbimage'></div>
    <div class='thumbtitle'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The thumbnails float left, in a grid:

```
.thumb {
  float: left;
}
```

The thumbtitles are shortened to fit on one line:

```
.thumbtitle {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  min-height: 1.25em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

When the user hovers over a thumbnail, the abbreviated thumbtitle is replaced with the full thumbtitle:

```
.thumb:hover .thumbtitle {
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

If the full thumbtitle does not fit on one line, then the hovered thumbnail box expands downward to accommodate the full title.

Here is my problem:

When the hovered thumbnail expands downward, the thumbnail below shifts right to get out of its way.  This is not the behavior I want.  I would like the expanded thumbnail to overlap, rather than push away, the thumbnail below.  That is, I want the hovered thumbnail box to expand downward without causing any of the other thumbnails to move.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```
.thumbtitle {
    position:absolute;
}
```

in order to remove them from the flow of the document, and

```
.thumb {
    position:relative;
}
```

to position `.thumbtitle` relatively to `.thumb`.

This way you can also add

```
.thumbtitle {
    max-width:100%; /* or width:100% */
}
```

Finally, add

```
.thumb:hover .thumbtitle {
    z-index:1;
}
```

to make it overlap the following elements.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ANvvR/